# Creating a WIX3.8 shortcut using C#

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.8

> Error  1   The Shortcut/@Id attribute's value, 'C:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppName With Spaces\AppName With Spaces\bin\Debug\APS.exe', is not a legal identifier.  Identifiers may contain ASCII characters A-Z, a-z, digits, underscores (_), or periods (.).  Every identifier must begin with either a letter or an underscore. C:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppName With Spaces\AutomatedIDSystemInstaller\Product.wxs   36  1   AutomatedIDSystemInstaller

I am trying to add an Advertised Shortcut to the Desktop for the user (Not Public/Desktop) on Windows 7.

The following code is in my ComponentGroup

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="ProductComponents">
    <File Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes">
      <Shortcut Id="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" 
                Name="MyProject Name"
                Advertise="yes" 
                Description="1-Click to Change all your passwords!" 
                WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
                ShortName="APS"                      
                Directory="DesktopFolder"/>
    </File>
  </Component>
```

Comment: Id is an identifier, not a path. Just make up a name like "ProjectShortcut".

Comment: I did that and now it says the Directory is not valid

Comment: Error 1 Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:DesktopFolder' in section 'Fragment:'.